# Syncing contact between salesforce and microsoft sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, salesforce

I am new to sharePoint and don't know very much about it.I want to sync my contacts from salesforce crm to sharePoint and vice-versa without any tool. What is best way to perform this activity and what problems can occurs in this process.

Is there any api or webservice concept behind  then also suggest me.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: without any tool but ask for webservice or api ? Try to explain better your scenario but before read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: tool means connector